# Dart: How to get char from String, and do comparison

Tags: dart

I am trying to get char from a string, and do comparison:

```
String aStr = ReadString(inputs);
String bStr = ReadString(inputs);

int diff = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (aStr.codeUnitAt(i) != bStr.codeUnitAt(i)) {
    diff++;
  }
}
```

However, I got the following errors in compilation process:

```
Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 7
#0      String.codeUnitAt (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:927)
#1      BoomerangDecoration (file:<>/HCPast/bin/hcpast.dart:49:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (file:<>/HCPast/bin/hcpast.dart:9:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:263)
#4      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:151)
```

I also tried charCodeAt, but it was said not a method from String.

Comment: Where are you getting `n` in the for loop? It seems you're accessing characters beyond the end of one of your strings...

Comment: n is the length of these strings. Besides, it should not be shown in the compilation session?

Comment: Do your two strings have the same length? The error message suggests that the first string is longer than the second and you try to access a position that does not exist on the second.

Comment: Thank you all. After I double check, it is already after compliation session. It should be beyond the end of string.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to be able to find the cause of the problem. I can see from the stack trace that the code is asynchronous, and it's unclear how `n` is computed, so even if your strings have the same length, maybe something changes between the time that `n` is computed and when it's used.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I double check, it is already after compliation session. The cause should be index beyond the end of string.